# Possble to have 2 files alternate for log4j, used every second time opening?

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to configurate 2 files to alternate as every second time starting the logging from log4j?

Like adding a new file but don't want to have more than 2 files?

Comment: Without reading the documentation: It will be possible, at least you can write your own appenders and/or handlers. But the overall questions should be: _What purpose do log files have that alternate every second (and thus are overwritten)?_ Maybe, I did not understad you correctly. [So what exactly are you trying to achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks, changed text!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think you confused OP into changing the title into something irrelevant.

Comment: Oh ok, changed again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your log4j configuration of appenders, you need to specify a `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` if you want the logs to roll-over based on application runs and you need to define a `max` attribute for your `DefaultRolloverStrategy` and set it to `2`

Assuming you're using log4j2 and an XML configuration it'd be something similar to this:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <YourAppenderOfChoiceHere>
            // Other parameters here
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2"/>
        </YourAppenderOfChoiceHere>
    </Appenders>
    // Other config stuff here
</Configuration>
```

Obviously replace `YourAppenderOfChoiceHere` with your appender of choice, and also add things like `Loggers` etc in order to make your configuration function properly.

Comment: What for log4j.properties file, is it possible ?

Comment: You could try to combine the `maxBackupIndex` argument which limits the amount of log files with adding a timestamp in the log file name, this would create a different log every time (since timestamp will be different every time) but would still limit it to 2 logs.